# wslite works with xml not inline

Tags: soap, groovy

If you use the XML version of this post is works,  but tearing my hair out to try and find out why the inline version does not. Its hardly a complex function!!

```
import wslite.soap.SOAPClient
import wslite.soap.*
import groovy.xml.Namespace

proxy = new SOAPClient("http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService?wsdl")

/*
// THIS WORKS
list = proxy.send(
'''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:ns="http://predic8.com/wsdl/crm/CRMService/1/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:get>
     <id>99</id>
    </ns:get>
 </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>'''
  )
    */

   //return list.getText()

//THIS DOES NOT
list = proxy.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService'){
body{
    get(xmlns:ns="http://predic8.com/wsdl/crm/CRMService/1/"){
        id(99)
        }
} //end body
} //end proxy

return list.getText()
```

Anyone able to fathom out why?

Answer (score 2):

Attributes should be passed as a Map, so the following change to your code should work.

```
...
'ns:get'('xmlns:ns': "http://predic8.com/wsdl/crm/CRMService/1/"){
...
```

or

```
...
get('xmlns': "http://predic8.com/wsdl/crm/CRMService/1/"){
...
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy.. Been all the way round the houses with combinations of namespace and not. If you run a getAll in that code it works perfectly well, and the service works in SoapUi etc so that is the frustrating part..

Comment: Got it! needs to be 'ns1:get'(...)